# Why is ArcGIS Server JavaScript API throwing a CORS error when Leaflet does not, for the same WMS layer?

Tags: leaflet, wms, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cors

I'm trying to add a publicly-accessible WMS layer to an ArcGIS Server JavaScript API v4 map, and am encountering a CORS error.

See the simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/umLot2jz/) which loads the ArcGIS JS API [WMS layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WMSLayer.html):

```
// ArcGIS WMS layer fails
const layer = new WMSLayer({
  url: "https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/historic-landfill/wms",
  sublayers: [{name: "Historic_Landfill_Sites"}]
});
```

This returns a CORS error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/historic-landfill/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities'
> from origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

(The demo is hosted on JSFiddle but the same behaviour occurs on my laptop during development, with the error message being for origin http://localhost, or if I host the HTML page elsewhere online).

Note that this same layer works when added to a Leaflet map ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/msz5xany/)), on the same machine, using the identical URL:

```
// Leaflet WMS layer works
var wmsLayer2 = L.tileLayer.wms('https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/historic-landfill/wms', {
  layers: 'Historic_Landfill_Sites',
  transparent: true,
  format: 'image/png'
});
```

How is Leaflet able to circumvent the CORS error, and can I use this approach to get the WMS layer to work in ArcGIS Server?

Comment: If you read ESRI docs about `WMSLayer` API, you can see the following: _The WMSLayer is used to create layers based on OGC Web Map Services (WMS). The WMSLayer initially executes a WMS GetCapabilities request, which might require CORS or a proxy page._ This call to `GetCapabilities` (which causes CORS error) is the main difference with Leaflet API, where no such call is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me quote https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors :

> This cross-origin sharing standard can enable cross-origin HTTP
> requests for:
>
> - Invocations of the `XMLHttpRequest` or Fetch APIs, as discussed above.
> - Web Fonts (for cross-domain font usage in `@font-face` within CSS), so that servers can deploy TrueType fonts that can only be loaded
>   cross-origin and used by web sites that are permitted to do so.
> - WebGL textures.
> - Images/video frames drawn to a canvas using `drawImage()`.
> - CSS Shapes from images.

Of that list, three are of interest for your question:

- Loading the `GetCapabilities` document via `fetch()`
- Loading map tiles in a `<canvas>`

  - Via 2D canvas' `drawImage()`
  - Via WebGL

While not explicitly stated, loading images via a [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), i.e. via a [`<img>` HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), is **not** subject to CORS.

Leaflet uses the latter method - one `<img>` per tile, *and* does not request the `GetCapabilities` document.

This is not without drawbacks - notably, the nefarious ["one pixel gap between tiles" bug](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3575), plus needing to specify all WMS parameters (instead of getting that information from the `GetCapabilities` document).

I don't know how the arcgis JS API works, but given your error message, it's safe to say it does request the `GetCapabilities` document via `fetch()`.

Do note that Leaflet plugins that perform canvas manipulation on tiles (e.g. TileLayer.NoGap, TileLayer.GL, TileLayer.Colorizr, etc), or that  perform either `GetCapabilities` or `GetFeatureInfo` requests, are subject to CORS restrictions.

> can I use this approach to get the WMS layer to work in ArcGIS Server?

Not without rewriting half of the code for the arcgis JS API (which is even not really an option since it would imply reverse engineering the code therefore angering esri's lawyers).

As an interim solution, you might want to consider setting up a [mapproxy](https://mapproxy.org) instance. The default value for its `Access-control-allow-origin` setting is permissive.

Comment: See my comment to the question about cause of the CORS error.

Comment: @TomazicM Yeah, I addressed that in an edit.

Comment: many thanks to both of you, I appreciate the thorough answer. I'll give the proxy approach a test - I'm also trying the Esri resource proxy approach, but this is causing its own cross-origin issues in my React app as the proxy uses a different port to the application. There's [another question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424986/how-to-use-esri-resource-proxy-with-react-and-arcgis-server-javascript-api) if you fancy diving further into the CORS rabbit hole with me ;)

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, but I swore to myself to never again touch any react code even with a 10-foot pole.